# segmentation fault on chromium embedded framework (CEF) SendMouseMoveEvent

Tags: linux, arm, chromium, chromium-embedded, headless

I have a headless browser which displays the content. I capture the created browser in the OnAfterCreated() method. When i geht the browser host and i want to send mouse events i get an segmentation fault. Any suggestions?

```
    CefMouseEvent mouseEvent;
    mouseEvent.modifiers = eventFlags;
    mouseEvent.x = mouseX;
    mouseEvent.y = mouseY;

    if (BrowserHandlerSingleton::CurrentBrowser != NULL)
    {
        CefBrowserHost * host = BrowserHandlerSingleton::CurrentBrowser->GetHost();
        // host->Invalidate(BrowserHandlerSingleton::PaintElementType::PET_VIEW);
        host->SendMouseMoveEvent(mouseEvent, false);
    }
```

Comment: What version of `CEF` are you using? What operating system?

Comment: Ignore the operating system part. Fact that your using `arm` you might be in untested waters.

Comment: I build CEF Release 2526 and I am on a CuBox-i 4x4 running armbian 4.5 (Debian Jessie Desktop)

Comment: You might need to ask on http://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php, your code looks fine.

Comment: Calling SendMouseEvent within the OnPaint method (OSR) works!

Answer (score 0):

When I use the CefRefPtr to declare the host everything is fine!

```
CefRefPtr<CefBrowserHost> host = BrowserHandlerSingleton::CurrentBrowser->GetHost();
```

Reference counting matters.